# requestFocusInWindow(boolean) has protected access in JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcomponent

I'm trying to  build the GUI for a program assignment that essentially has 2 buttons on top start on the left and resume on the right and the the panel sits on the bottom. but it telling me:

> Error: requestFocusInWindow(boolean) has protected access in
>   JComponent

I have run into this once before and I feel like I'm not understanding what that means does any one have a good explanation I Googled around and can't seem to find anything so I think it's probably something silly.

Here is the code I am using to construct the GUI:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PendulumWindow {

    protected JFrame pendFrame;
    protected JPanel pendPanel;
    protected JButton resume;
    protected final int SIZE_X = 500;
    protected final int SIZE_Y = 450;
    protected Dimension pendPanSize = new Dimension(SIZE_X, SIZE_Y);

    public PendulumWindow() {

    }

    public PendulumWindow(String s) {
        makePanel();
        makeFrame();
    }

    public void makePanel() {
        pendPanel = new JPanel();

        pendPanel.setPreferredSize(pendPanSize);
        pendPanel.setFocusable(true);
        pendPanel.requestFocusInWindow(true);
        pendPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
   }

   public void makeFrame() {
        pendFrame = new JFrame("Pendulum");
        start = new JButton("start");
        resume = new JButton("resume");

        //---------- FRAME PROPERTIES ----------//

        pendFrame.setSize(500,500);
        pendFrame.setVisible(true);
        pendFrame.setResizable(true);
        pendFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //---------- ADD ELEMENTS TO FRAME ----------//

        pendFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pendFrame.add(start, BorderLayout.WEST);
        pendFrame.add(resume, BorderLayout.EAST);
        // pendFrame.add(pendPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        PendulumWindow window = new PendulumWindow("Pendulum");
   }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with calling pendPanel.requestFocusInWindow() ?

Comment: thats exactly what Reimeus suggested and it worked. I didn't realize that there was a public requestFocusInWindow(); and must have overlooked it when i looked at the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs show that [requestFocusInWindow(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28boolean%29) is `protected` so can only be called by subclasses of `JComponent`. Instead you should use the publicly accessible [requestFocusInWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29).

Comment: this was very helpful i must have missed that public requestFocusInWindow() when i look at the docs. thank you!

Comment: AFAIK The temporary flag is for use by the [focus subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html). Fields such as the `permanentFocusOwner` get set depending on this flag. Generally you can let Swing take care of this and use `public void requestFocusInWindow()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `requestFocus()`, not `requestFocusInWindow()`.

Comment: -1, Read the API documentation for the requestFocus() method. Its suggests you should be using the requestFocusInWindow() method.

Comment: @camicr: You don't distinguish from WHERE it is called. "SavgStorm" wants to call it from OUTSIDE of the component. You cannot call a protected method from OUTSIDE.

Comment: Don't mix two methods: requestFocusInWindow() without parameters is public, you can call it. requestFocusInWindow(boolean temporary) is protected, you cannot call it from outside.   Sure, technically you can subclass JPanel and call requestFocusInWindow(boolean temporary) via some your public method or even make requestFocusInWindow(boolean temporary) public. But before doing it, first think what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I stand by my statement (because the advice came from the API documentation on the requestFocus() method). Don't use the requestFocus() method. Use the `requestFocusInWindow()` method.

Comment: @mentallurg requestFocus is discouraged because its functionality can not be guaranteed across platforms. Your are (as the docs say) recommended to us requestFocusInWindow. From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus()) *"Because the focus behavior of this method is platform-dependent, developers are strongly encouraged to use requestFocusInWindow when possible."*